# get last order id before each order row for each customer in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a table:customer_ids, order_ids,product_id and order_dates and I want to add a column to my table that contains last order date of each customer that bought this product(in python).

```
 customerid         orderid     productid    orderdate    
 -----------------------------------------------------    
 1                  1           1            2018/01/01    
 1                  1           2            2018/01/01
 1                  2           3            2018/01/04
 1                  3           1            2018/01/10
 2                  5           1            2018/01/14
 1                  7           3            2018/01/17
 2                  12          2            2018/01/12
 1                  20          1            2018/01/23
```

and i want to have a table like this:

```
 customerid         orderid     productid    orderdate    lastorderdate    
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------    
 1                  1           1            2018/01/01    NA    
 1                  1           2            2018/01/01    NA        
 1                  2           3            2018/01/04    NA    
 1                  3           1            2018/01/10    2018/01/01    
 2                  5           1            2018/01/14    NA    
 1                  7           3            2018/01/17    2018/01/04    
 2                  12          2            2018/01/12    NA    
 2                  20          1            2018/01/23    2018/01/14
```

what should i do?

Comment: it's my fault..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
df=df.sort_values(['customerid','productid'])
df['last_order']=df.groupby(['productid','customerid'])['orderdate'].\
                                            apply(lambda x: x.shift())
print(df)
```

And the output is:

```
   customerid  orderid  productid  orderdate last_order
0           1        1          1 2018-01-01        NaT
3           1        3          1 2018-01-10 2018-01-01
7           1       20          1 2018-01-23 2018-01-10
1           1        1          2 2018-01-01        NaT
2           1        2          3 2018-01-04        NaT
5           1        7          3 2018-01-17 2018-01-04
4           2        5          1 2018-01-14        NaT
6           2       12          2 2018-01-12        NaT
```

you can also use `df = df.sort_index()` to get the index aligned as original.

**Output based on your data:**

```
df=df.sort_values(['customer_id','product_id'])
df['last_order']=df.groupby(['product_id','customer_id'])['date'].\
                                            apply(lambda x: x.shift())
print(df.sort_index().head(20))

     row_id       date  customer_id  product_id last_order
0        1 2018-04-07            4           1        NaT
1        2 2018-04-07            4           1 2018-04-07
2        3 2018-04-07            4           1 2018-04-07
3        4 2018-04-07            4           1 2018-04-07
4        5 2018-04-07            4           1 2018-04-07
5        6 2018-04-07            4           1 2018-04-07
6        7 2018-04-07            4           1 2018-04-07
7        8 2018-04-07            4           1 2018-04-07
8       13 2018-04-09            4           1 2018-04-07
9       49 2018-04-13            4           1 2018-04-09
10     106 2018-04-20            4           1 2018-04-13
11     115 2018-04-20            4           1 2018-04-20
12     142 2018-04-27            4           2        NaT
13     143 2018-04-27            4           2 2018-04-27
14     149 2018-04-29            4           2 2018-04-27
15     168 2018-05-02            4           1 2018-04-20
16     169 2018-05-02            4           1 2018-05-02
17     229 2018-05-08            4           5        NaT
18     230 2018-05-08            4           5 2018-05-08
19     231 2018-05-08            4           5 2018-05-08
```

Comment: my data  is big. i send you data for a specific customer

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work yet. for example for rowid=268 and date=2018/05/15 . the last_order=2018/05/20 is false.

Comment: is it possible for you to check it with my modified data? (correct date format). because when i run it i get false result.

Comment: @samen added output, check which line are you facing the error.(if at all)

Comment: yes that's true. when i check code with only customer_id=4, the result is true. but when i check it with complete data, the result is false.

Comment: @samen its working for the test data, there may be other dependencies which you might have to look at but the example and the requirement you had stated is met by the answer. :)

Comment: yes, thanks. it worked. i removes other columns from my dataset. and it worked well.